# Remove row from CSV data if one field value matches value from a list

Tags: python

I'm doing some manipulation on a CSV file using Python and the csv module. I take a CSV file, do some operations, and output an XML file. Very simplified, but the input data looks similar to this:

```
name,group
joe,staff
jane,student
bill,staff
barry,support
jack,student
```

I have a list as follows:

```
outputList = ['staff', 'support']
```

Essentially, what I want to do is remove the line of data if the `group` field isn't contained in the `outputList`. So what I would end up with is:

```
name,group
joe,staff
bill,staff
barry,support
```

The main reason I need to remove the rows is because I then need to sort by `outputList` (which is a lot longer than in this example, and in a specific non-alphabetical order).

Doing the sorting is relatively easy:

`csvData = sorted(csvData, key=lambda k: (outputList.index(k['group'])))`

However, obviously without removing the rows that aren't needed I get an error that the `group` value isn't in the `outputList`.

Is there an easy way of removing the data, or do I just need to iterate over each row and check whether the value is present? I've seen methods of doing it when you just have two lists. E.G.

```
data = ['staff', 'support', 'student']
csvData = [data for data in csvData if data not in outputList]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no other way to filter the data without scanning all the data of course, you can simply do something like this:

```
import csv

def parser(fp, groups):
    with open(fp) as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fp)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1] in groups:
                yield row

csvData = parser('~/some_loc/file.csv', outputList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your csv into a pandas dataframe df.
The you can use:

`df = df[df.group.isin(outputList)]`
Isin creates a boolean series(mask) which you can use to select only the relevant rows.

Comment: I should mention that my approach also involves looping over your data. However pandas is made for Data Science application and handling big data. So the implemented function are often faster than self-engineered loops. Also you can do a lot more complex task with dataframes and you can load and save from/to the most common formats.